# How to only change the color for click div item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(function(){
    $("#title div").on("click", function(){
      $(this).parent().css("color", "#000000");
      $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">
      <div class="book-title lv1">A</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">B</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">C</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">D</div>
</div>
```

What I am going to do is set red color on click item and make others color to black everytime.

How can I change my code to do that?

Comment: i have a css only solution if javascript isn't necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#title div").on("click", function(){
      $(this).siblings().css("color", "#000000");
      $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">
      <div class="book-title lv1">A</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">B</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">C</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, plash. But why .parent() is not working?

Comment: @aBloomer: That's because `.parent()` will only set color to any text node inside it, but there is no text node inside the parent. Text node are present inside the children of the parent or basically the siblings of the clicked div. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach in my opinion is to have a class `.selected`

then do the following:

```
    $(function(){
        $("#title div").on("click", function(){
          $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the children black and then color the other one red.

```
$(function(){
    $("#title div").on("click", function(){
      $(this).parent().children('div').css("color", "#000000");
      $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
$(function(){
$("#title div").on("click", function(){
  $(".book-title").css("color", "#000000");
  $(this).css("color", "red");
 });
});
```